# Moving list items issue

Tags: html, css, html-lists

The problem is, if I put any margin on any element which is inside the product div or the slider div the whole list-items are moving down.

```css
.product-slider {
  margin-top: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

.slide-item {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
}

.product, .slider {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.product {
  width: 25%;
}

.slider {
  width: 5%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="product-slider">
  <li class="slide-item"><div class="slider"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></div></li>
  <li class="slide-item"><div class="product">Test</div></li>
  <li class="slide-item"><div class="product">Test</div></li>
  <li class="slide-item"><div class="product">Test</div></li>
  <li class="slide-item"><div class="slider"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try using `padding` instead of `margin`

Comment: can you show your issue in fiddle/snippet?

Comment: i 've already tried padding outputs the same

Comment: Please start by properly describing what you actually want to achieve here. Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also try this:

```
.product-slider{
      margin-top: 16px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .slide-item{
      list-style-type: none;
      display: inline;
      width: 80%;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: auto;
    }

    .product, .slider{
      height: 200px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align:text-top;
    }

    .product{
      width: 25%;
    }

    .slider{
      width: 5%;
    }

<ul class="product-slider">
  <li class="slide-item">
    <div class="slider"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></div>
  </li>
  <li class="slide-item">
    <div class="product">Test</div>
  </li>
  <li class="slide-item">
    <div class="product">Test</div>
  </li>
  <li class="slide-item">
    <div class="product">Test</div>
  </li>
  <li class="slide-item">
    <div class="slider"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.product-slider{
      margin-top: 16px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .slide-item{
      list-style-type: none;
      display: inline;
      width: 80%;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: auto;
    }
    
    .product, .slider{
      height: 200px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .product{
      width: 25%;
    }
    
    .slider{
      width: 5%;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="product-slider">
      <li class="slide-item slider"><div class="slider-left"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></div></li>
      <li class="slide-item product"><div class="product-item">Test</div></li>
      <li class="slide-item product"><div class="product-item">Test</div></li>
      <li class="slide-item product"><div class="product-item">Test</div></li>
      <li class="slide-item slider"><div class="slider-right"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></div></li>
    </ul>
```